# Facebook Login: It doesn't redirect to the Facebook app installed?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

Hi Facebook Login: It doesn't redirect to the Facebook app installed ?

The user already had `Facebook installed and he was logged in`, no need to login facebook, in application already login in default facebook application. no need to login again how to solved this issue?

Any one have idea give me suggestion.

EDIT: is it possible to get user `name` and `id` to my application, default facebook account login to mobile?

Comment: how do you have implemented this?

Comment: I remember having problems with this a long time ago. It has something to do with the key or id that fb provides to use their sdk. Try to get the key or id programmatically and compare it with the key or id fb gave you, it might be different.

Comment: can you show some codes? the problem might be on your implementation. somewhere there.

Comment: What Facebook SDK are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

Use latest facebook SDK.

Please also check that in your facebook sdk there is one java file with name Facebook.java

Just check authorize function in that class.

It should be like below:

```
public void authorize(Activity activity, String[] permissions,
        int activityCode, final DialogListener listener) {

    boolean singleSignOnStarted = false;

    mAuthDialogListener = listener;

    //THIS CODE IS EDITED BY SHREYASH FOR NOT ALLOW THE DEFAULT FACEBOOK APP
    // Prefer single sign-on, where available.
    if (activityCode >= 0) {
        singleSignOnStarted = startSingleSignOn(activity, mAppId,
                permissions, activityCode);
    }
    // Otherwise fall back to traditional dialog.
    if (!singleSignOnStarted) {
        startDialogAuth(activity, permissions);
    }
}
```

Please check it. and let me know.
Hope it will help you a lot as it help me lot.

Enjoy Coding... :)